# Sending MIDI clock only (bpm count) through USB to sequencer [terminal]

Tags: command-line, sound, usb, music, midi

I'm trying to send bpm to my Arturia MicroBrute sequencer through USB. It has USB MIDI input through that port as it can be seen on many YouTube links and I easily manage to sync it with Reaper DAW on Windows machine.

Working with MIDI is kinda new for me on linux and I don't know **how to send MIDI clock for sequencer through terminal?** (I need to do that live on stage through ssh so I need terminal solution).

I've already used amidi to send whole midi files, but I don't know how to send only bpm for playing on sequencer without any notes.

Comment: `amidi` or `aplaymidi`? Where do you get the clock from? Or are you asking how to generate it?

Comment: I want to generate bpm. With amidi I was able to send midi file and played it, but I want to send clock only.  Best option will be to generate it through giving command with specified tempo with some tool I'm looking for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://das.nasophon.de/klick/

> **klick** is an advanced command-line based metronome for [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/). It allows you to define complex tempo maps for entire songs or performances.

---

http://lists.linuxaudio.org/pipermail/linux-audio-user/2009-August/061724.html

> I've attached a CLI metronome using the ALSA sequencer, that optionally 
>   outputs MIDI Clock messages.

Comment: This works flawlessly with 2nd option (I prefer ALSA over JACK). Only trick I don't get in first place was to put **-m** flag to send master clock to my sequencer which was necessary in this point to do so. Thank you very much!